# Magento emails not working error log 403

Tags: cpanel, magento-1.9

All emails in my Magento 1.9.2.4 shop : invoice , new registration , contact us.... not work. I recive error log 403. 
I haven't make any changes on the site. Can the reason be in the cPanel?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following commands:

```
find ./ -type f | xargs chmod 644
find ./ -type d | xargs chmod 755
chmod -Rf 777 var
chmod -Rf 777 media
```